# Sequentially Increment an Inner Loop Based on Outer Loop Value

Tags: r, loops

I apologize if this has been answered elsewhere, but I can't find a solution (or the proper terms to phrase the question).

In the example below, q reaches a maximum of 20.

How would I adjust the code below if I wanted q to have values of 1:20 for k=1, then 21:40 for k=2, and 41:60 for k=3?

```
for (k in 1:3) {
  for (q in 1:20) {
    print(paste("k =", k, "q= ",q))
   } 
}
```

Comment: `for (k in 1:3) for (q in 20*(k-1)+1:20) { ... }`

Comment: Thanks @r2evans !

Comment: @r2evans After further use, your solution is best.  Would you care to post it as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
for (k in 1:3) {
  for (q in 20*(k-1)+1:20) {
    # ...
  }
}
```

Comment: A minimalistic answer. _Perfection is when you can't take anything away._

Comment: Yes, sometimes the most direct questions don't benefit from a wordy answer. I generally like to "explain" things, but I don't really know what to say here ...

Answer (score 2):

There's not built-in shortcuts for this, you have to do some math. I would suggest this:

```
for(q in seq(from = (k - 1) * 20 + 1, length.out = 20))
```

Mind your parentheses!

Comment: Thanks Gregor!  I was attempting such math but didn't think of the `seq` function, etc..